# Error pago con paypal al querer iniciar sesion

Tags: php, paypal

Estoy teniendo un problema que no se cual ya que es mi primera vez usando la integracion de paypal...

Estoy tratando de realizar la integracion para pagos recurrentes y lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera...

En la pagina donde se muestran los paquetes y los botos para direccionar a la pagina de paypal lo realizo de la siguiente manera

> paquetes.php

```
<?php

    $loggedUser = $_SESSION["id"];

    $date = getdate();

    $day = $date["mday"];
    $month = $date["mon"];
    $year = $date["year"];

    //PayPal variables
    $paypalURL     = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $paypalID     = 'Correo de paypal';
    $successURL = 'http://localhost/AmoriaDateFinal/FrontEnd/success';
    $cancelURL     = 'http://localhost/AmoriaDateFinal/FrontEnd/cancel';
    $notifyURL     = 'http://localhost/AmoriaDateFinal/FrontEnd/paypal_ipn';

    $itemName = 'Suscripcion a Amoria!';
    $itemName2 = 'Suscripcion a Amoria Plus!';
    $itemName3 = 'Suscripcion a Amoria Hot!';
    $itemNumber = 'MS/'.$day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year.'/'.$loggedUser;

    //subscription price for one month
    $itemPrice = 25.00;

?>

<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
        <!-- identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">
        <!-- specify a subscriptions button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <!-- specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="MXN">
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="paypalAmt" value="<?php echo $itemPrice; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="paypalValid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
        <!-- custom variable user ID -->
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $loggedUser; ?>">
        <!-- specify urls -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $cancelURL; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $successURL; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $notifyURL; ?>">
        <!-- display the payment button -->
        <input class="paypal_button" type="submit" value="Comprar Suscripción">
</form>
```

en la ventana de success.php tengo este codigo

```
<?php
    //Database credentials
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'nombreBaseDatos';

    //Connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    //Display error if failed to connect
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

if(!empty($_GET['item_number']) && !empty($_GET['tx']) && !empty($_GET['amt']) && $_GET['st'] == 'Completed'){
    //get transaction information from query string
    $itemnumber = $_GET['item_number'];
    $txnid = $_GET['tx'];
    $paymentgross = $_GET['amt'];
    $currencycode = $_GET['cc'];
    $paymentstatus = $_GET['st'];
    $custom = $_GET['cm'];

    var_dump($_GET);

    //Check if subscription data exists with the TXN ID
    $prevPaymentResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usersubscriptions WHERE txnid = '".$txnid."'");

    if($prevPaymentResult->numrows > 0){
        //get subscription info from database
        $paymentRow = $prevPaymentResult->fetch_assoc();

        //prepare subscription html to display
        $phtml  = '<h5 class="success">Thanks for payment, your payment was successful. Payment details are given below.</h5>';
        $phtml .= '<div class="paymentInfo">';
        $phtml .= '<p>Payment Reference Number: <span>MS'.$paymentRow['id'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Transaction ID: <span>'.$paymentRow['txnid'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Paid Amount: <span>'.$paymentRow['paymentgross'].' '.$paymentRow['currencycode'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '<p>Validity: <span>'.$paymentRow['validfrom'].' to '.$paymentRow['validto'].'</span></p>';
        $phtml .= '</div>';
    }else{
        $phtml = '<h5 class="error">Your payment was unsuccessful, please try again.</h5>';
    }
}elseif(!empty($_GET['itemnumber']) && !empty($_GET['tx']) && !empty($_GET['amt']) && $_GET['st'] != 'Completed'){
    $phtml = '<h5 class="error">Your payment was unsuccessful, please try again.</h5>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PayPal Subscriptions Payment Payment Status</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>PayPal Subscriptions Payment Status</h1>
    <!-- render subscription details -->
    <?php echo !empty($phtml)?$phtml:''; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

y en el apartado donde recibo la IPN

```
<?php

/*
 * Read POST data
 * reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
 * issues with array data in POST.
 * Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
 */        
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

// Read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

/*
 * Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
 * Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
 */
$paypalURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init($paypalURL);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);

/*
 * Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
 * Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
 */ 
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    //Include DB configuration file
    include 'dbConfig.php';

    $unitPrice = 25;

    //Payment data
    $subscrid = $_POST['subscrid'];
    $payeremail = $_POST['payeremail'];
    $itemnumber = $_POST['itemnumber'];
    $txnid = $_POST['txnid'];
    $paymentgross = $_POST['mcgross'];
    $currencycode = $_POST['mccurrency'];
    $paymentstatus = $_POST['paymentstatus'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom'];
    $subscrmonth = ($payment_gross/$unitPrice);
    $subscrdays = ($subscr_month*30);
    $subscrdatefrom = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $subscrdateto = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($subscr_date_from. ' + '.$subscr_days.' days'));

    if(!empty($txn_id)){
        //Check if subscription data exists with the same TXN ID.
        $prevPayment = $db->query("SELECT id FROM usersubscriptions WHERE txnid = '".$txnid."'");
        if($prevPayment->num_rows > 0){
            exit();
        }else{
            //Insert tansaction data into the database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO usersubscriptions(userid,validity,validfrom,validto,itemnumber,txnid,paymentgross,currencycode,subscrid,paymentstatus,payeremail) VALUES('".$custom."','".$subscrmonth."','".$subscrdatefrom."','".$subscrdateto."','".$itemnumber."','".$txnid."','".$paymentgross."','".$currencycode."','".$subscrid."','".$paymentstatus."','".$payeremail."')");

            //Update subscription id in users table
            if($insert){
                $subscriptionid = $db->insertid;
                $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET subscriptionid = {$subscriptionid} WHERE id = {$custom}");
            }
        }
    }
}
die;
```

el problema es que al momento de dar clic al boton, me manda a la pagina de sandbox y muestra todos los datos correctamente pero al momento de que doy clic en iniciar sesion me aparece el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]